# How to handle passing usize to a C function that expects uint32_t?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I am writing a Rust wrapper around a C library. The C library provides the following function:

```c
void lib_foo(const unsigned char *buf, uint32_t buf_len);
```

I have created the following `extern` wrapper:

```rust
fn lib_foo(buf: *const u8, buf_len: u32);
```

and the following high-level wrapper:

```rust
pub fn foo(buf: &[u8]) {
    unsafe { lib_foo(buf.as_ptr(), buf.len() as u32) }
}
```

However, the cast from `usize` (the type of `buf.len()`) to `u32` may cause the size to be truncated. What is the best way of dealing with this?

Comment: I assume you can't change the library function? Then you probably have to live with the cast and the warning.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I cannot change the C library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please use the [`libc`](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate for types.

That is: `extern fn lib_foo(buf: *const libc::c_uchar, buf_len: libc::uint32_t);`

While it is slightly longer, it will avoid making assumption (`unsigned char` maps to `u8`) and makes the translation automatic.

---

Then, onto the high level wrapper.

Without any assumption, the simplest solution is to panic, and document this.

```
/// Calls `lib_foo`, ...
///
/// # Panics
///
/// If the size of the buffer is strictly greater than 2^32-1 bytes.
pub fn foo(buf: &[u8]) {
    assert!(buf.len() <= (std::u32::MAX as usize));

    unsafe { lib_foo(buf.as_ptr() as *const _, buf.len() as libc::uint32_t) }
}
```

Then, depending on the domain, other options may arise:

- saturation may be an option (using `std::cmp::min`)
- repeated calls may be another
- ...

in any case, if the difference of behavior is observable to the user, *document*.

Comment: For `unsigned char` it is reasonable, but isn't lengthening `u32` to `libc::uint32_t` excessive, as `uint32_t` clearly and explicitly intended to always represent a 32-bit unsigned integer, just like `u32`?

Comment: @Vi.: On the other hand, when you have a C header file to translate to Rust, it's so much easier to just slap `libc::` in front of the type name and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

- If it makes sense to read/write chunks with `lib_foo`, wrap it in a loop that processes chunks of 2**32 (at increasing offsets) and then processes the remainder. In most cases it will skip the loop, but in the exceptional case, it will just call `lib_foo` more than once
- If truncating is acceptable behavior for `lib_foo`, truncate and tell user somehow
- If it's not, complain loudly if len >= 2**32